# What is Maximum simultaneous requests limitation is calculated across all orgs that access the same host?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits

We have a managed App to integrate with a third platform, so our app do a lot of API calls in Apex code. I reviewed the [Apex Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) and found the following item:

> Maximum simultaneous requests to URLs with the same host for a callout request.
>
> The host is defined by the unique subdomain for the URL—for example, www.mysite.com and extra.mysite.com are two different hosts. This limit is calculated across all orgs that access the same host. If this limit is exceeded, a CalloutException is thrown.

I am confused that the **This limit is calculated across all orgs that access the same host**, how to define **across all orgs**? If I have two customers A and B, will A's org simultaneous requests effect B?

Comment: `This limit is calculated across all orgs that access the same host` - Seems to me that would be extremely impractical to enforce. And for little or no benefit. Why should someone on a EU pod care what is going on with the NA or CS pods. The overhead of trying to monitor all the API calls to a single host name across all the pods would be huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some [clarification](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/859294037286584320) from the Salesforce Docs team about the following emphasized line:

> The host is defined by the unique subdomain for the URL—for example, www.mysite.com and extra.mysite.com are two different hosts. **This limit is calculated across all orgs that access the same host.** If this limit is exceeded, a CalloutException is thrown.

Their [response](https://twitter.com/salesforcedocs/status/859465679686205440):

> The limit is correct, but is rarely exceeded. It only applies to orgs on the same server in the same pod. We'll update the doc accordingly.

That makes more sense. If one particular Salesforce server starts to have problems communicating with an external service then it isn't going to grind to a halt waiting for it. It will affect all orgs using that server, but the limit isn't applied across servers.